# Is this proof that $\sqrt 2 \in R$ correct?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, alternative-proof

In Stephan Abbot's understanding analysis, he proves that the square root of two exists and equals $\sup(T)$ where $T = \{t \in R: t^2<2\}$ (Theorem 1.4.5). I proved this differently then in the book and I was wondering if my solution is correct.

If $a \neq \sqrt 2$, $a^2 >2$ or $a^2 < 2$. If $a^2<2$, choose $k^2 = \frac{a^2+2}{2}$ (it will be assumed k is positive). Then $$a^2 < 2 \Rightarrow a^2 + 2 < 4 \Rightarrow \frac{a^2 +2}{2} < 2$$ or $k \in T$. Similarly, $$a^2<2 \Rightarrow 2a^2 < 2+a^2 \Rightarrow a^2 < \frac{a^2 + 2}{2}$$ which means a is not an upper bound for T. If $a^2 > 2$, again set $k^2 = \frac{a^2 + 2}{2}$. It follows that $$a^2 > 2 \Rightarrow a^2+2>4 \Rightarrow \frac{a^2 + 2}{2} > 2$$ so $k$ is an upper bound for T. Similarly, $$a^2>2 \Rightarrow 2a^2 >2+a^2 \Rightarrow a^2 > \frac{a^2 + 2}{2}$$ Which means k is an upper bound which is less than the supremum which is a contradiction. Since the axiom of Completeness requires a supremum  exists for a non-empty bounded set, $a^2 = 2$ so $\sqrt 2$ must exist in R. $QED$

Comment: How do you know there is some $k > 0$ satisfying $k^2 = \frac{a^2 + 2}{2}$?

Comment: Does that make my proof fall apart?

Comment: The proof is very wrong. At least you need to say what properties of real numbers you assume true. Say, in the first line you state that every number $\ne 2$ is either $>2$ or $<2$. Why?

Comment: Since we are working in a context where we don't assume the square root of 2 exists, we are really overstepping if we assume a square root of some fairly arbitrary real number exists as part of the proof. However, there are approximation methods that avoid this circular logic. I believe Rudin does something like the Newton method to prove square roots exist.

Comment: JCAA, some properties are assumed such as either a = b, a < b or a > b